# on('click') executando mais de uma vez

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quando clico em uma area e depois no botão .mais1 pela primeira vez executa corretamente a função mas se eu clicar em uma area depois em outra e clicar no botão .mais1 ele executa a função duas vezes, a função é executada o número de vezes que eu clico no elemento.

Não consegui identificar o erro, alguem já teve esse problema? Alguem sabe a solução?

```
 $("area").click(function(){         

    var escrever = '';
    var a = $(this).attr('class');
    var x = $.inArray(a,paises1);
    var clicado = x;

    t = ataques_possiveis[x].length;
    meus_territorios_tamanho = meus_territorios.length;

    if(opcao==2){

        for(w=0; w<meus_territorios_tamanho; w++){
            if(meus_territorios[w]==x){
                $(".selecione").html(paises2[x]);
            }
        }

        $('body').on('click','.distribuir .mais1',function(){

            if($('.selecione').text()!='Selecione'){
                var local = $(this).parent().parent().children('h2').text().replace(':','');
                var ter = $.inArray($(".selecione").text(),paises2);
                var pos_local = $.inArray(local,nomes_locais);

                for(var z=0; z<meus_territorios_tamanho; z++){
                    if(local==nomes_locais[0]){//verifica o tipo de exercito
                        if((meus_territorios[z]==x)&&(distribuir_locais[pos_local]>0)){
                            distribuir_locais[pos_local] = distribuir_locais[pos_local] -1;
                            exercitos[ter] = exercitos[ter]+1;
                            $('.'+ter).text(exercitos[ter]);
                            $(this).parent().parent().children('.dist_local').text(distribuir_locais[pos_local]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }                                 
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: precisamos do html, obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Na verdade ele vai ocorrer toda vez que o evento click elemento `area` for clicado. Pode ser que o `.mais1` esteja dentro dele, então possa parecer que é o clique nele que está fazendo, mas não necessariamente.

O que você pode fazer é tirar a criação do evento click do `.mais1` de dentro do clique de `area`, já que você está atribuindo o evento no `body` mesmo. Se o funcionamento do `.mais1` depende do clique em `area` e que a variável `opcao`(que me parece ser global) seja igual a dois, você pode replicar a condição no `if` dentro do evento:

```
$('body').on('click','.distribuir .mais1',function() 
{
    if(opcao == 2 && $('.selecione').text()!='Selecione')
```

Outra solução é usar o `.off()`, mas não recomendo porque seria uma gambiarra, mas seria útil caso a regra fosse "o clique em `.mais1` só deveria funcionar após um clique no `area`. Funcionaria assim:

```
$('body').off('click','.distribuir .mais1').on('click','.distribuir .mais1')
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Deu certo já tinha ficado hrs tentando resolver!

Comment: @Thadeu se quiser já pode aceitar a resposta

Comment: @Math vocês unificaram o usuário dele?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown sim, fizemos um merge de usuários